# How to resolve complex JSON and put it in list into list using Retrofit

Tags: java, android, json, android-studio, retrofit2

I have JSON as shown below

```
{
"status" : "succesfull",
"items": [
    {
        "id" : "1",
        "name": "apple",
        "counrty": "USA"
    },
    {
        "id": "2",
        "name": "banana",
        "country": "Jamaica"
    },
    {
        "id":"3",
        "name": "potatoes",
        "counrty": "Belarus"
    },
    ...
   ]
  }
```

> Let's say, country is varied, and I don't know which countries will be in list

I need to make a list as below:

[image]

> Any solutions will be appreciated

```
public class Response {
  String status;
  ArrayList<Items> items;      
}



public class Items{
   String id;
   String name;
   String country;
}
```

Comment: You'll have to write some code to do the structure conversion.

Comment: I don't know how to create list in the list

Comment: @JustAhead have you tried expandable listview -  https://www.androidhive.info/2013/07/android-expandable-list-view-tutorial

Answer (score 0):

You can do it this way,  (sorry for bad formatting) 
Make sure to add getter/setter methods in your structure class.

```
JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(responseString);
Response response = new Response();

if(jsonObj.has("status")){ 
response.setStatus(jsonObj.getString("status"));
}

if(jsonObj.has("items")) {
 JSONArray array = jsonObj.getJSONArray("items");
 ArrayList<Items> list =new ArrayList();

for(i=0;i<array.length;i++){ 
     JSONObject json = array.get(i); 
     Items item = new Items();
     item.setId(json.getString("id"));
     item.setName(json.getString("name"));
     item.setCountry(json.getString("country"));
     list.add(item);
}
}
response.setItems(list);
```

Comment: Is there any specific reason for not suggesting JSON parsing libraries like Gson, Jackson or Moshi in your answer? I'm not telling your procedure is wrong or shouldn't be followed but it makes code very long and tomorrow if we want to change any `key` in JSON structure this code style make developer's life worse. :)

Comment: The disadvantage of using library is when you apply proguard rules and want to obfuscate your code, these classes will be excluded as the proguard rules for these library may be different, which itself is a huge reason for security purpose.

Answer (score 0):

#### Hi Just Ahead,

Put your JSON to any JSON parser like here http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/
Than you need to select Parcelable / Serializable and you will get automatically generated POJO classes.
Than you have to set up retrofit instance with okHttp / gson, create dao interface where you implement your all methods to call your JSON.

Answer (score 0):

Your POJO will look like this:

```
public class Response{
private List<ItemsItem> items;
private String status;

public void setItems(List<ItemsItem> items){
    this.items = items;
}

public List<ItemsItem> getItems(){
    return items;
}

public void setStatus(String status){
    this.status = status;
}

public String getStatus(){
    return status;
}


class ItemsItem{
    private String counrty;
    private String name;
    private String id;
    private String country;

    public void setCounrty(String counrty){
        this.counrty = counrty;
    }

    public String getCounrty(){
        return counrty;
    }

    public void setName(String name){
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getName(){
        return name;
    }

    public void setId(String id){
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getId(){
        return id;
    }

    public void setCountry(String country){
        this.country = country;
    }

    public String getCountry(){
        return country;
     }

 } }
```

Create a RecyclerView with CustomLayout XML with a TextView and a ListView.

On RecyclerViewAdapter class just set Title and Lists

custom layout for recyclerView will look like this

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Title Goes here" />

   <ListView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/_150sdp"/></LinearLayout>
```